# How to get all marked characters in a string with ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

For example, my string is:

```
"abcd :e fghi :j klmn"
```

I want to get `:e` and `:j` which with special mark `:`. Can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
"abcd :e fghi :j klmn".scan(/:\w+/)
# => [":e", ":j"]

"abcd :egg fghi :joke klmn".scan(/:\w+/)
# => [":egg", ":joke"]
```

Comment: Thank you. If scan full words in a string. Use `scan(/:\w+/)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
"abcd :e fghi :j klmn".split(' ').select{|e| e.include? ':'}
=> [":e", ":j"]
```

or

```
"abcd :e fghi :j klmn".split(' ').select{|e| e =~ /^:\w/ }
=> [":e", ":j"]
```